# Notepad/Notepad++ Quote entire line if comma is present

Tags: notepad++

I have a rather large data set that is requiring quotes (") to be placed at beginning and end of the line only if the line includes a comma somewhere within the line (could be different places depending on the line - for example not always the 5th character).  Is there a way to automate this a bit instead of manually reviewing each line and typing the quotes in?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: This is really basic, what doesn't work with your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(.*,.*)
```

(search for one or more symbols)
and replace with

```
"\1"
```

(replace first group with quotation marks around)
[image]